# setting dropbox as custom backp on whm/cpanel error

Tags: perl, backup, cpanel, dropbox, whm

I am trying to set dropbox as custom backup destination following below cpanel blog. The connection is working, but the backup files are not being transferred to DropBox. And when I press validate to custom backup destination it gives following error .

https://blog.cpanel.com/cpanel-whm-custom-backup-transport-example-dropbox/

```
Error: Validation for transport “dropbox” failed: Could not list files in 
destination: Executed /usr/local/bin/backup_transport_dropbox.pl ls / 
remotehost remoteuser : 2018-08-26T15:54:21 [WebService::Dropbox] [ERROR] 
https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder {"path":"/"} -> [400] Error in 
call to API function "files/list_folder": request body: path: Specify the root 
folder as an empty string rather than as "/". at 
/usr/local/share/perl5/WebService/Dropbox.pm line 184.
```

I am new to dropbox api and have no idea of perl so could not figure out what is discusses on below links.

https://github.com/silexlabs/unifile/issues/77

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correctly indicating that [the Dropbox API expects the value `""` when referring to the root alone](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#path-formats). The code is instead sending the value `"/"`. This looks like a bug in the code.

It looks like you've already opened an issue with the developer for this:

https://github.com/CpanelInc/backup-transport-dropbox/issues/3

They should update the code to use `""` when referring to the root folder on Dropbox.

Comment: Thank You for your comment. Yes I already have opened issue at Github repo. I found there were already 2 issues which were unanswered and had not thought they would reply soon.